# How to ignore item if it is null

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to post on a form, but it is not always necessary to post all items. How do I do that?

```
 const { title, subtitle, content, createdAt, image } = request.body;
      const { key } = request.file;
      let url = `${process.env.APP_URL}files/${key}`;
      const post = await Post.create(
        {
          image: url,
          title,
          subtitle,
          content,
          createdAt,
          createdby: request.userId,
        }
```

Comment: If you want to let user create a post despite missing arguments (items), then you could set default values which would be used if there is none provided.

Comment: @JakubASuplicki In this case, the default value is set to null

Comment: Is there any specific redundant item that you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of your problem, you might need to consider how it is ultimately going to be displayed on the front-end.

Let's imagine you designed front-end that expects all of the above items. If you still wanted to let users create a post without either of them, then you would end up having missing elements in your UI, it could even cause errors depending on how you render them.

The way around it would be to conditionally render each item. In other words, `if` item is not `null` then add it to your `DOM`.

Alternatively, you could set `default` values, other than `null`.

For example, the image could be a generic image url if there is none provided:

```
image: url || 'directory/to/your/default/image'
```

**Edit** to handle no file scenario:

```
let url = 'directory/to/your/default/image'
if (request.file !== undefined && request.file) {
  const { key } = request.file;
  url = `${process.env.APP_URL}files/${key}`;
}
```

I hope it gives you some ideas on how to approach it.

Comment: I would like it to be in the image field. But it presents this error. Cannot destructure property `key` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

Comment: That seems to be a different issue, not related to your question in this case. The line causing it seems to be `const { key } = request.file;`
Would need more information in order to debug this.

Comment: In this case, the request.file is not triggered because there is no field in it. I would like to know how to ignore this

Comment: I suppose you could first check whether there is a file in your request and only then overwrite the URL. Otherwise, you would leave it to the default image. Edited the answer.